# How to add crosshairs to magnifying glass?

Tags: autoit

I'm stuck adding crosshairs to the magnifying glass. [This](https://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/24154-au3-zoom/#comment-168674) is what my source code is based on:

```
#include <GUIConstants.au3>

$MagWidth = 50
$MagHeight = 50
$MagZoom = 3

Global $dll[3], $DeskHDC, $GUIHDC

$dll[1] = DllOpen ( "user32.dll")
$dll[2] = DllOpen ( "gdi32.dll")

Global $GUI = GUICreate ("Zoom x2 Au3", $MagWidth * $MagZoom, $MagHeight * $MagZoom, _
    MouseGetPos (0), MouseGetPos (1), $WS_POPUP+$WS_BORDER, $WS_EX_TOPMOST)
Global $divider_x = GUICtrlCreateGraphic(5,25,$MagWidth * $MagZoom,1)

GUISetState(@SW_SHOW)

Global $LastPos[2] = [0,0]

While 1
    MAG()
    $MousePos = MouseGetPos()
    If ($LastPos[0] <> $MousePos[0] Or $LastPos[1] <> $MousePos[1]) Then
        WinMove("Zoom x2 Au3", "", $MousePos[0] + $MagWidth/2 + 5, $MousePos[1])
        $LastPos[0] = $MousePos[0]
        $LastPos[1] = $MousePos[1]
    EndIf

    Sleep(10)
WEnd

Func MAG()
    $DeskHDC = DLLCall("user32.dll","int","GetDC","hwnd",0)
    $GUIHDC = DLLCall("user32.dll","int","GetDC","hwnd",$GUI)
    If Not @error Then
        DLLCall("gdi32.dll", "int", "StretchBlt", "int", $GUIHDC[0], "int", _
            0, "int", 0, "int", $MagWidth * $MagZoom, "int", $MagHeight * $MagZoom, "int", $DeskHDC[0], "int", _
            MouseGetPos (0) - $MagWidth/2, "int", MouseGetPos (1) - $MagHeight/2, "int", $MagWidth ,"int", $MagHeight, _
            "long", $SRCCOPY)
        DLLCall("user32.dll","int","ReleaseDC","int",$DeskHDC[0],"hwnd",0)
        DLLCall("user32.dll","int","ReleaseDC","int",$GUIHDC[0],"hwnd",$GUI)
    EndIf
EndFunc

Func OnAutoItExit()
    DllClose ( $dll[1] )
    DllClose ( $dll[2] )
EndFunc
```

I tried adding thin lines using `GUICtrlCreateGraphic()` and `GUICtrlCreateLabel()` but that just reduces the magnified display on the GUI's window. How do I add a crosshair?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here I show you a solution, I've made some time:

```
#include <WindowsConstants.au3>
#include <WinAPI.au3>
#include <StructureConstants.au3>
OnAutoItExitRegister('OnAutoItExit')

Global $iMagZoom = 5


Global $iMagWidth = Ceiling(100/$iMagZoom)
Global $iMagHeight = Ceiling(100/$iMagZoom)

Global $hDCDesk, $hDCZoom, $hPen
Global $hUser32 = DllOpen("user32.dll")
Global $hGDI32 = DllOpen("gdi32.dll")

Global $__hMouseProc = DllCallbackRegister("_MouseProc", "long", "int;wparam;lparam")
Global $__hHook = _WinAPI_SetWindowsHookEx($WH_MOUSE_LL, DllCallbackGetPtr($__hMouseProc), _WinAPI_GetModuleHandle(0))

Global $hCross = GUICreate('', 48, 48, -1, -1, $WS_POPUP, $WS_EX_TOPMOST)
WinSetTrans($hCross, '', 10)
GUISetCursor(3, 1, $hCross)

Global $hZoom = GUICreate("Zoom Window", $iMagWidth * $iMagZoom, $iMagHeight * $iMagZoom, _
    MouseGetPos(0), MouseGetPos(1), $WS_POPUP+$WS_BORDER, $WS_EX_TOPMOST)

GUISetState(@SW_SHOW, $hCross)
GUISetState(@SW_SHOW, $hZoom)

; once at start, than from mouse-callback-function
_Magnify()


While 1
    Sleep(10)
WEnd

Func _ende()  ; called by mouse left click
    Exit
EndFunc

Func _Magnify($_iX=-1, $_iY=-1)
    Local Static $fInit = True
    If $fInit Then
        $fInit = False
        $hDCDesk = (DLLCall($hUser32, "int", "GetDC", "hwnd", 0))[0]
        $hDCZoom = (DLLCall($hUser32, "int", "GetDC", "hwnd", $hZoom))[0]
        $hPen = (DLLCall($hGDI32, "int", "CreatePen", "int", 0, "int", 3, "int", 0x00800000))[0] ; 0=PS_SOLID, dark-blue (0x00BBGGRR)
        DLLCall($hGDI32, "int", "SelectObject", "int", $hDCZoom, "hwnd", $hPen)
        $_iX = MouseGetPos(0)
        $_iY = MouseGetPos(1)
    EndIf
    Local $iW = $iMagWidth * $iMagZoom, $iH = $iMagHeight * $iMagZoom
    If Not @error Then
        DLLCall($hGDI32, "int", "StretchBlt", "int", $hDCZoom, "int", _
            0, "int", 0, "int", $iW, "int", $iH, "int", $hDCDesk, "int", _
            $_iX - $iMagWidth/2, "int", $_iY - $iMagHeight/2, "int", $iMagWidth ,"int", $iMagHeight, _
            "long", $SRCCOPY)
        ; draw the crosshair
        _GDI32_DrawLine($hDCZoom, ($iW/2)-2, $iH/8, ($iW/2)-2, 3*($iH/8), $hGDI32)     ; vertical
        _GDI32_DrawLine($hDCZoom, ($iW/2)-2, 5*($iH/8), ($iW/2)-2, 7*($iH/8), $hGDI32) ; vertical
        _GDI32_DrawLine($hDCZoom, $iW/8, ($iH/2)-2, 3*($iW/8), ($iH/2)-2, $hGDI32)     ; horicontal
        _GDI32_DrawLine($hDCZoom, 5*($iW/8), ($iH/2)-2, 7*($iW/8), ($iH/2)-2, $hGDI32) ; horicontal
    EndIf
EndFunc

Func _GDI32_DrawLine(ByRef $_hDC, $_iX0, $i_Y0, $_iX1, $i_Y1, $_hDll=-1)
    If $_hDll = -1 Then $_hDll = "gdi32.dll"
    Local $tCurrent = DllStructCreate("struct; long X;long Y; endstruct")
    DllCall($_hDll, "int", "MoveToEx", "int", $_hDC, "int", $_iX0, "int", $i_Y0, "ptr", DllStructGetPtr($tCurrent))
    DllCall($_hDll, "int", "LineTo", "int", $_hDC, "int", $_iX1, "int", $i_Y1)
    Return $tCurrent
EndFunc

Func _MouseProc($_nCode, $_wParam, $_lParam)
    Local $tMSLLHOOKSTRUCT = DllStructCreate("struct; long X;long Y; endstruct; " & _
        "DWORD mouseData; DWORD flags; DWORD time; ULONG_PTR dwExtraInfo;endstruct", $_lParam)
    If $_nCode < 0 Then Return _WinAPI_CallNextHookEx($__hHook, $_nCode, $_wParam, $_lParam)
    Local $iX = $tMSLLHOOKSTRUCT.X, $iY = $tMSLLHOOKSTRUCT.Y
    Switch $_wParam
        Case $WM_LBUTTONDOWN
            _ende()

        Case $WM_MOUSEMOVE
            WinMove($hCross, "", $iX -24, $iY -24)
            Local $iXz = ($iX +24 + $iMagWidth*$iMagZoom > @DesktopWidth) ? $iX -(24 + $iMagWidth*$iMagZoom) : $iX +24
            Local $iYz = ($iY +24 + $iMagHeight*$iMagZoom > @DesktopHeight) ? $iY -(24 + $iMagHeight*$iMagZoom) : $iY +24
            WinMove($hZoom, "", $iXz + $iMagWidth/2, $iYz)
            _Magnify($iX, $iY)
    EndSwitch
    Return _WinAPI_CallNextHookEx($__hHook, $_nCode, $_wParam, $_lParam)
EndFunc

Func OnAutoItExit()
    DLLCall($hUser32, "int", "ReleaseDC", "int", $hDCZoom, "hwnd", $hPen)
    DLLCall($hUser32, "int", "ReleaseDC", "int", $hDCDesk, "hwnd", 0)
    DLLCall($hUser32, "int", "ReleaseDC", "int", $hDCZoom, "hwnd", 0)
    DllClose($hUser32)
    DllClose($hGDI32)
    _WinAPI_UnhookWindowsHookEx($__hHook)
    DllCallbackFree($__hMouseProc)
EndFunc
```